# SQL Oracle 10g request

Tags: oracle10g

i have a report to give tomorrow and i have a question i can't answer : 
"find the month showing the most in the table"

so if there are 5 "december" and 3 "february" it will show "december"

```
select extract(month from date_table) from table 
  where(extract(month from date_table)) 
    having count(*) >= all (select count(*) from table))
```

date_table is a column with date type in table

I think it is something like this but i can't get it to work correctly.

Help me please,
thanks !

Comment: You've tagged this for Oracle, SQL Server, and MySQL.  Which database are you actually using?  Different databases support different SQL syntax options.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
select MonthName(date_table) Mo, count(*) cnt
from table 
Group by MonthName(date_table)
order by cnt Desc
Limit 1
```

- Group by months
- Include count
- order the count descending
- limit to the first.

ORACLE:

```
With CTE as(
select to_char(date_table,'MONTH') Mo, count(*) cnt
from table
Group by To_char(date_Table, 'MONTH')
order by cnt Desc)
Select Mo from CTE where cnt = (Select max(Cnt) from CTE)
```

Might be a faster way using over partition syntax.

This creates the results first then uses the temporary results to get the max cnt and only display months having that max.

Assuming duplicates can be listed so if dec and feb both show 5... then what?  Show both, show one?

Source of MonthName function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname

Comment: thanks it helps, but it is not exactly what i asked,
what you wrote shows this : 
MO CNT 
12 2 
7 1 
1 1 
4 1 

i want :

MO
December

for example if december is the most in the table. 
there is one more sub-request left i think, the one saying only show the most count(month).

And yeah, if it could show all top equal like feb and dec in your example(both 5)

Comment: ah so you want the month name not the month numeric value? if so Updated. assuming mysql

Comment: not really important, it can be 12 but i want only the most, not the list with all the months showing

Comment: Then Limit 1 didn't work the way it should.  is this mySQL, Oracle, or SQL Server?  Amended answer to include versions for Oracle/MySQL

Comment: Ah okay, i'm using oracle 10g

Comment: Oracle example will work, but the analytic version would work faster if I can remember the syntax